# Leaflet + Opendata + WGS 84 = Geographic Transformation?

Tags: leaflet, wgs84

I'm visualize Opendata from Austria in shp and json Format.
I'm able to map the data with leaflet but the markers and tracks are shifted... So I contacted the responsible department and got the following response - and I have no clue how I can managed this in leaflet:

> Die geometrische Projektion der OGD-Daten für Tirol
>
> ist MGI_Austria_GK_West
>
> hier die Projektionsparameter: MGI_Austria_GK_West WKID: 31254
>   Authority: EPSG
>
> Projection: Transverse_Mercator
>
> False_Easting: 0,0 False_Northing: -5000000,0 Central_Meridian:
>   10,33333333333333 Scale_Factor: 1,0 Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,0 Linear
>   Unit: Meter (1,0)
>
> ETRS_1989_To_WGS_1984+MGI_To_ETRS_1989_5

That code works fine, but how can i implement the wgs?

```
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([47.25, 11.39], 14)

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
var geoJsonLayer;

    shp("natur/RNA_NSGEBPolygon").then(function(geojson){
        //do something with your geojson
        console.log(geojson);

    geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {

            filter: function(feature, layer) {
                if(feature.properties){ 
                    return true;
                }//End if
            },//end filter
            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NAME);
            }

        })//end L.geojson
        //.addTo(mymap);

    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    mymap.addLayer(markers);
    mymap.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
```

Thanks for you Help

Comment: pls share your code

Comment: ...code added in the original posting. greetings

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you receiving the data with the coords in `latlng` format but L.geoJSON needs `lnglat`

Add `coordsToLatLng` in you L.geoJSON to convert:

```
geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {

            filter: function(feature, layer) {
                if(feature.properties){ 
                    return true;
                }//End if
            },//end filter
            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NAME);
            },

    coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
        //                    latitude , longitude, altitude
        //return new L.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0], coords[2]); //Normal behavior
        return new L.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]);
    }

        })//end L.geojson
        //.addTo(mymap);
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43549799/8283938

Comment: Thanks for you answer... lang lat are not mixed. The track is only shifted by a few meters... 
They told me that I have a false "project" and should use the wgs84...no clue how to implement that in lefalet... greetings

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded QGIS (Freeversion)

imported the SHP File and than exported the file as Geojson layer. Important is the dialog: "KBS" and there you change to: "EPSG: 4326 - WGS84" and so I managed the correct implementation...
cheers